# Adesso T10 stops working in Blender

Tags: hardware

I just purchased a new computer which has Windows 10 Pro installed on it - my previous computer had Win 8.1.  I installed my Adesso T10 graphics tablet driver, etc. but have run into an issue where the tablet stops responding after about a minute while in Blender.  If I exit Blender or go to another program the tablet is working fine but when I switch back to Blender it stops working . . . any ideas?  I've reinstalled the drivers and have the latest version of Blender as well . . . .

Comment: Never mind - problem solved . . . I have to have the tablet's sensitivity set above the 50% mark in the Adesso driver software . . . now it works like a charm . . . suh-freaking-weet . . . a-sculpting we will go.